# making a jpa oneToMany relationship effective?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have written a very basic and naive oneToMany relationship between a ChatComponent and its Chat Messages like this:

```
@OneToMany
List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;
```

This basically works, i.e., doing something like:

```
ChatMessage chatMessage = vo.toDomainObject();
chatMessage.setDate(new Date());
//Add the message to the chat component
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(chatMessage);
chat.addChatMessage(chatMessage);
em.persist(chat);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

gets the job done. Only, looking at the SQL logs, I can see that every time, the entire collection of chat messages is persisted again. That's obviously something I can't afford, given chat messages could quickly add up in the thousands.

The SQL that gets repeated for each chat message is as follows:

```
Hibernate: insert into BaseComponent_ChatMessage (BaseComponent_id, chatMessages_id) values (?, ?)
```

preceded by:

```
Hibernate: delete from BaseComponent_ChatMessage where BaseComponent_id=?
```

From this I conclude that Hibernate doesn't have a way to know that we're not dealing with a whole set of new objects and that it should keep those it already has.

I'm sure there is a way to add (and persist) only *one* member of the many side of a relationship, but I can't seem to find out how.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the only way to avoid the entire list of chat messages to be persisted each time is to establish a bidirectional relationship between the chat component and its chat messages

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent")
List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_CHAT_COMPONENT_ID", nullable=false)
private ChatComponent parent;
```

then in the addChatMessage function I can simply add a message to the chat component without having to persist it, then persist the chat component and that works beautifully.

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    chat.addChatMessage(chatMessage);
    em.persist(chat);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `hashCode` and `equals` methods of your `ChatMessage` class, so that Hibernate can know that these are the same objects.

Use your IDE to generate hashCode() and equals(). In Eclipse it is right click > Source > Generate hashCode and equals, and choose the property which is `@Id` for your entity.

Also, try adding the `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` attribute to `@OneToMany`

Comment: Hi Bozho,

That makes good sense indeed. However, I can see that the first statement issued is:

    Hibernate: delete from BaseComponent_ChatMessage where BaseComponent_id=?

...which seems to indicate that it's the ChatComponent (ChatComponent inherits from BaseComponent here) that's not recognised as already existing.

I have tried implementing hashCode() in both classes by just letting it return the id of the entity. I'm not sure this is the way to go though, and I'm a bit confused about what to do in the equals method aswell.

Thank you however, this definitely seems to be a good lead :-)

Comment: Mmmh, I've tried every possible combination of generating hashCode and equals on both ends of the relationship, using Eclipse, but I'm still having n+1 inserts :(
thanks anyway!

Comment: try adding the cascade=CascadeType.ALL attribute